# Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'UITextRange'

Tags: ios, swift, string, uitextfield

I really don't know why this doesn't work out :( 
I want to show the text in the text field.

```
var motionManager = CMMotionManager()

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextField!
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.2

    motionManager.startGyroUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, error) in
        if let myData = data {
            if myData.rotationRate.x > 3 {
                textView.text("Dein Tablet ist schief!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`UITextField.text` is a property of type `String`, not a setter function. You should use the assignment operator (`=`) to set its value.

```
textView.text = "Dein Tablet ist schief!"
```

Answer (score -3):

Use assignment operator to set a value to textView

```
textView.text = "Dein Tablet ist schief!"
```